# How do you print items in a linked list in reverse iteratively, using Java?

Tags: java, linked-list, iteration

I am trying to find a way to print the items inside a linked list in the reverse order that they appear in the linked list using Java and without using recursion.

Comment: How's your search going?

Comment: Stack might help you

Comment: are you using java list? where is your code

Answer (score 0):

Follow references and get to the end of the list. If it's a doubly-linked list, follow back references and print as you go. However if you're iterating a singly linked list, you have to push the references onto a stack or something